# Iterate over a CSV file Python

Tags: python, regex, csv, iterator

I have a CSV file that looks like this

```
a,b,c
d1,g4,4m
t,35,6y
mm,5,m
```

I'm trying to replace all the m's and y's preceded by a number with 'month' and 'year' respectively. I'm using the following script.

```
import re,csv
out = open ("out.csv", "wb")
file = "in.csv"
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for ss in reader:
        s = str(ss)
        month_pair = (re.compile('(\d\s*)m'), 'months')
        year_pair = (re.compile('(\d\s*)y'), 'years')

def substitute(s, pairs):
    for (pattern, substitution) in pairs:
        match = pattern.search(s)
        if match:
            s = pattern.sub(match.group(1)+substitution, s)
    return s

pairs = [month_pair, year_pair]
print (substitute(s, pairs))
```

It does replace but it does that only on the last row, ignoring the ones before it. How can I have it iterate over all the rows and write to another csv file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)m','months',s)
'a,b,c\nd1,g4,4months\nt,35,6y\nmm,5,m'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)y','years',s)
'a,b,c\nd1,g4,4m\nt,35,6years\nmm,5,m'
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
print (substitute(s, pairs))
```

your variable `s` is only the last line in your file. Note how you update `s` in your file reading to be the current line.

Solutions (choose one):

- You could try another `for`-loop to iterate over all lines.
- **Or** move the substitution into the `for`-loop where you read the lines of the file. This is definitely the better solution!

You can easily lookup how to write a new file or change the file you are working on.